# VBA Reference Tables in Index Match

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

EDIT:  I am getting  a `#VALUE!` error when I try to run this function. It works if I just do the `If statement` so the logic seems good. The issue is recreating the `INDEX MATCH MATCH` formula. I am trying to reference column 15 of a table called 'Headcount' and find the corresponding result in the 'Region' column.

tblHeadcount:

```
Name          Region    
Bob           001    
Jake          003    
Bill          001
```

```
Function CO_GLREFORM(CellRef1 As Range, CellRef2 As Range, CellRef3 As Range) As String
    Dim tblHeadcount As ListObject
    Dim matchColResult As Long
    Dim matchRowResult As Long
    Dim indexResult As Variant

    '------THIS IS THE CODE THAT CREATES #VALUE! ERROR
    'Set tblHeadcount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Headcount")
    'matchColResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(CellRef3, tblHeadcount.ListColumns(15).DataBodyRange, 0)
    'matchRowResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(tblHeadcount.HeaderRowRange(16), tblHeadcount.TotalsRowRange, 0)
    'indexResult = WorksheetFunction.Index(tblHeadcount.DataBodyRange, matchColResult, matchRowResult)

    If UCase(CellRef1) = "CONFERENCE" Or UCase(CellRef1) = "TRAINING" Then
       '-----THIS IS THE CODE GENERATED (WITH ADJ) FROM THE MACRO RECORDER------ 
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CellRef2 &""-""&INDEX(Headcount,MATCH(CellRef3,Headcount[Name Verification],0),MATCH(Headcount[[#Headers],[Region]],Headcount[#Headers],0))&""-7210.0100"""
       '-----THIS IS MY ATTEMPT TO RECREATE THE FORMULA 
       'CO_GLREFORM = CellRef2 & "-" & indexResult & "-7210.0100"
    Else
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "CO_GLREFORM = CellRef2 &""-""&INDEX(Headcount,MATCH(CellRef3,Headcount[Name Verification],0),MATCH(Headcount[[#Headers],[Region]],Headcount[#Headers],0))&""-7210.0105"""
        'CO_GLREFORM = CellRef2 & "-" & indexResult & "-7210.0105"
    End If

    '--------THIS IS THE FORMULATE I AM REPLICATING----------------
    'If(OR(CellRef1="CONFERENCE",CellRef1="TRAINING"),CellRef2&"-"& _
        INDEX(Headcount,MATCH(CellRef3,Headcount[Name Verification],0), MATCH(Headcount[[#Headers],[Region]],Headcount[#Headers],0))&"-7210.0100",CellRef2&"-"& _
        INDEX(Headcount,MATCH(CellRef3,Headcount[Name Verification],0),MATCH(Headcount[[#Headers],[Region]],Headcount[#Headers],0))&"-7210.0105")

End Function
``
```

Comment: You are missing the range criterion on the Index.

Comment: BTW, you can avoid the triple check of the different case variants for CellRef1 by just using `if UCase(CellRef1) = "CONFERENCE"`

Comment: Why don't you write the cell into the worksheet grid for troubleshooting and sort out what is wrong with it. Then, once it works, put it into VBA.

Comment: @teylyn thank you for the UCase(). I saw this online but it didn't click until now. The formula works in the spreadsheet, I am just struggling with translating to VBA. Do you mean to do the 'Record Macro' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `WorksheetFunction.Match(tblHeadcount.HeaderRowRange(16), tblHeadcount.TotalsRowRange, 0)` is a whole waste of time. It finds the position of the text in the column header of column 16 in the column headers. Just use the number 16 in the Index instead.

The variable `matchColResult` returns the row number, the variable `matchRowResult` contains the column number. This is a recipe for disaster and does not help with troubleshooting.

I created a table with 17 columns and these lines now run without error:

```
Set tblHeadcount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Headcount")
'use a different name for this: matchColResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(CellRef3, tblHeadcount.ListColumns(15).DataBodyRange, 0)
matchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(CellRef3, tblHeadcount.ListColumns(15).DataBodyRange, 0)
'remove this: matchRowResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(tblHeadcount.HeaderRowRange(16), tblHeadcount.TotalsRowRange, 0)
' the above match for column 16 can just be expressed by the number 16
indexResult = WorksheetFunction.Index(tblHeadcount.DataBodyRange, matchRow, 16)
```

One reason for the #Value! error is that the specified range is not valid, e.g. if you look for column 16 in a table that has fewer than 16 columns.